# Remapping TFS in same Computer without code download again

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

When I tried to map local path in TFS with Visual Studio 2013 to another location in same computer, there is prompt to Download/Update code again.

In my case Project size is near by 12 GB, and I don't want to download it again, as it too much time taken process.

So please share the easy way to achieve it.

Old path is **E:/Project-TFS/2013/Code** and I want to it with New Path **E:/Code**, without downloading code again.

Comment: try to copy files in new folder and then try to change workspace Local PATH

Comment: You have tried it, it's not working, If u knowledge about it, then share steps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply adding a linked folder, i.e.

`mklink /J E:\Code E:\Project-TFS\2013\Code`

This way the mapping stays the same but you can use the other path.
Be careful not confusing the TFS client and avoid doing TFS operations on the shorter path.

Comment: Hi Giulio, Thanks for your response, but I want to shorten the path, as 256 characters are allowed for full path of files, and in my case this limitation is crossing, so need to shorten to Path, So can u share the solution for it, that's why I can remap the path to E:/Code as on place of other path.

Answer (score 0):

TFS workspaces are unique to your user name and the remote computer name and workspace information is stored both on your local computer and on the server.

If you want to change the mappings, you would have to perform "Get" to update the workspace:

[image]